# Angular 6 - Hide or Show a Div in component triggered from a Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a service which has a method that does something.

**service.ts:**

```
doSomething() {
    // Does something here
}
```

This service talks with the component below:

**myComponent.ts**

I have: myComponent.html which has a div:

```
<div class="myDiv">Something Here</div>
```

What I want to so is to show and hide the div by code in the service doSomething() method.

**Like this:**

```
doSomething() {

    1. Show myDiv   
    2. // Do something here
    3. Hide myDiv
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you will need to do it in the component, not the service. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Particulary I insert into doSomenthing() method the set of a flag value for control the div.

**COMPONENT**

```
doSomething() {
  service
    .doSomething()
    .subscribe(
       r => {
          this.show = true;   
          2. // Do something here
          this.show = false;  
       }
    );
}

<div *ngIf="show" class="myDiv">Something Here</div>
```

But this code must stay into the component not in the service.

Comment: I think that `this.show = true` should be executed before subscribing to the observable.

Comment: Not necessary, all depends the finally of the code but inside of subscribe method we can ensure the response.

Comment: With your current code, the div will not be visible during the asynchronous operation of the observable (e.g. making an HTTP call to get data from a remote database).

Comment: He has not specified what he needs to do, but he wants to do :D

Answer (score 4):

Add the ngIf attribute to the markup:

```
*ngIf="IAmDoingSomething"
```

Within the component you can do the following:

```
export class MyDoSomethingComponent{
public IAmDoingSomething = false;
...
   invokeServices = async  () => {
       this.IAmDoingSomething = true;
       await doSomething();
       this.IAmDoingSomething = false;
    }
...
}
```